# Modify List<string> to convert contents to hyperlinks

Tags: c#, string, list, hyperlink

I have a `List<string>` that get's populated with URLs.  What I'd like to do is convert the contents of the `List` to hyperlinks that the user can click on.  I've seen a bunch of examples of how to do this, but most of them were to insert in to an email, or switch the word *here* to a hyperlink.  I just don't know what I'm looking at, so it's a little confusing.  Here's what I have:

```
List<string> lstUrls = new List<string>();
//PROGRAM GETS URLS FROM ELEMENTS IN HERE....
foreach (string s in lstUrls)
{
    s = "<a href=\"%s\"></a>";    //THIS DOESN'T WORK...
}
```

I don't want to change the content of the string - just to be able to display as a hyperlink.  For example, one string value will be https://www.tyco-fire.com/TD_TFP/TFP/TFP172_02_2014.pdf; and how Stack Overflow displays it as a link, that's what I would like to accomplish.

I know I'm obviously botching the syntax.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In a WPF `ListBox`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can´t change the content of a `List<T>` while iterating it using `foreach`. But you can using `for`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lstUrls.Count; i++)
{
    var s = lstUrls[i];
    lstUrls[i] = "<a href=\"" + s + "\">" + s + "</a>";
}
```

A bit easier to read was this:

```
lstUrls[i] = String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>", s);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use linq for it:

```
lstUrls = lstUrls.Select(s => $"<a href=\"{s}\"></a>").ToList();
```

Or rather displaying the url in it:

```
lstUrls = lstUrls.Select(s => $"<a href=\"{s}\">{s}</a>").ToList();
```