# c# - itemsource text to hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of links that I would like to make to hyperlink, anchor tag is not working. Is there another way I can convert the strings to link? I'm using `<ItemsControl>` bind to `LinkList.Link`

Here's what I've tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.LinkList.Link.Count; i++)
{
    var link = this.LinkList.Link[i];
    this.LinkList.Link[i] = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link + "</a>";
           //String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>", link );
}
```

Both (in comment) didn't work. I referred to this : [Modify List<string> to convert contents to hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288094/modify-liststring-to-convert-contents-to-hyperlinks)

Comment: So, what exactly doesn't work? And how are you presenting these links to the user?

Comment: @Stefan it's displaying <a href="link">link</a> like that, should be able to click it as hyperlink and go to internet browser

Comment: We need to see how you are using these Links. Without that information we cannot help

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to display those URL strings as a clickable hyperlink directly on the program window and allow the user click it, the following answers will help you, but remember to mark it as the answer. If it needs to be output as HTML, It seems that you should provide more useful information... And: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a Hyperlink in the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl as follows:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LinkList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Link}" />
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

As you can see, there is also an event on the Hyperlink, "RequestNavigate", which has a handler in code behind as follows:

```
   private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
   {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        e.Handled = true;
   }
```

Alternatively of course, you could bind the Command of the Hyperlink to carry out the navigation using the MVVM pattern.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LinkList, Mode=OneWay}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                     
       <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Link}">
         Link Text
        </Hyperlink>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You probably need your XAML template to be a Hyperlink bound to the url.